# How to use multiple spring-data applications with a shared database

Tags: jakarta-ee, redis, spring-data, hazelcast, distributed-caching

I have a spring application which uses spring-data to access a database. Now there is also another application, which needs to update the same database using just Hibernate/JPA to access the data.

If I update the data from the APP2, they will not be visible in the APP1 through the spring-data, because the underlying EntityManager would no be refreshed.

Is there any out-of-the-box solution how to provide this functionality? Obviously, what I can think of is:

- create a common REST layer to provide these operations
- Shared distributed cache like Hazelcast, Redis

I want to avoid the first option, because of the need to refactor the APP1. I am not sure about how the second would work, i.e.:

- the shared objects between APP1 and APP2 would be stored in distributed cache and always read from there.
- the updates would be executed through the respective access layer - the APP1 would use its spring-data repositories, the APP2 its Hibernate/JPA service (however, the EntityManager would still not be updated with possible changes from the other application).

Comment: What do you mean by 'they won't be visible in APP1 through spring-data'? Using `spring-data`, you can perfectly have 2 apps sharing a domain object and use the same DB. Which doesn't mean you should but that's a different thing. Can you explain on why/how it doesn't work for you?

Comment: If you get an entity from the spring-data repository in the APP1. Then you update that entity in the APP2 (which runs on a different server). Then, if you get that entity again in the APP1, it will not contain the updated data, because the entity will be fetched from the L1 cache. Unless you refresh the entityManager the APP1 will not see the updated data.

Comment: Ok, I see you point. You want the data to be consistent immediately. For things like that, Redis seems like a no-brainer even though it kinda depends on your use case

Comment: Yeah, Redis would do the job, but I would like to keep the existing spring-data repositories and was hoping, that there is some (spring) module which can provide this for the existing spring-data repositories. In other words, we have limited resources for refactoring and want keep as much of the existing implementation as possible.

Comment: How about [spring-data-hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast) ? Allows you to work with a distributed store via Spring Data, and connect the distributed store to the database,

Comment: What is your persistence layer ATM? Some kind of MySQL or similar? Have you just tried to switch to Redis (and tweak what needs to be tweaked)?

Comment: We use Postgres for the DB. Spring-data-hazelcast seems promising, but if I understand it correctly, the update of the data would still need to go also through the JPA repos into the DB. How would this work in the context of the transactions/stale data/versions, etc....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around and testing, I've actually found out, that Spring-data together with Hibernate handles this situation correctly.

I've based my test on pure Hibernate/JPA and when using two EntityManagers, correctly I didn't see the changes made through one of them in the another one (I created the EntityManager as a service class member during construction). However, what spring-data does is, that it opens a new Hibernate Session for every invocation of a @Transactional method and close it when it's done.

So the problem rather is in the particular business logic, because it depends on the context of the @Transactional method if it is fine for it to "possibly" work with stale data during the invocation of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spring-data-hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/spring-data-hazelcast) with [Mapstore API](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#loading-and-storing-persistent-data). This gives you minimal impact on your apps but requires Mapstore implementation. If you choose to use hazelcast in embedded mode then that might be even better because you don't have to manage a separate central cache. Hazelcast scales out/in based on your application requirements

Comment: This [code](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-data-jpa-hazelcast-migration) might show some way.

Comment: Yes, I've actually seen that implementation. But I think the use-case there is a bit different. They use the distributed hazelcast to speed-up the translations, i.e. for reading. They do not update the data from the application. The JPA repositories are used for the hazelcast to load-up the data. I am interested in propagating the changes in the database across multiple applications (with spring-data, hibernate/JPA, etc...)